# Residue for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(x^{2}+1\right)^{3}} d x$ problem with second derivative.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Compute residue for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
>  \frac{1}{\left(x^{2}+1\right)^{3}} d x$

$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{\left(z^{2}+1\right)^{3}} $$
I have problem with second derivative: 
Where I compute $\operatorname{Res}[f(z), i] = \frac{1}{2!}\lim_{z\mapsto i } (z-i)^{3} \frac{d^2}{dz^{2}}f(z) $

but second derivative is:
$$
\frac{d^2}{dz^{2}}f(z) =\frac{6 \left(7 z^2-1\right)}{\left(z^2+1\right)^5}= \frac{6 \left(7 z^2-1\right)}{\left(z+i)^5(z-i\right)^5}
$$

Where is a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is that you computed

$$(z-i)^{3} \frac{d^2}{dz^{2}}f(z)$$

instead of

$$\frac{d^2}{dz^{2}}\Big[(z-i)^{3}f(z)\Big].$$

Comment: aaa yes, many thanks